# iPad display different webpage until added to home screen

Tags: javascript, ipad

Hi ive searched liked crazy and im unable to find an answer.. On www.asidemag.com using an ipad it will ask you to add to homescreen (but the page that is display is NOT the same page when youve added it to the homescreen!) hard to explain but ill try a little deeper.

1. go to asidemag.com on an ipad it will ask you to add it to your homescreen and thats it no other part of the site is displayed nor can be navigated too.
2. if you add it to the home screen and click the icon the magazine will load without adding it to the homescreen you'll never see the mag.

Now ive got scripts galore that can prompt you to add to home screen but not the other part.

looking at the html whilst on an ipad i think it might have something to do with the following:-

```
var hasFlash = function(){
    for(i=0; i<navigator.plugins.length; i++){
        if (navigator.plugins[i].name == "Shockwave Flash") return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

before it theres a form action which looks like `<input type="hidden" name="a" vale"" id="a"/>` and after the above theres `document.getElementById('a').value=navigator.userAgent;`

There are 8 different input types a-h and also 8 element types a-h  if you need the whole of the script i will have to type it in manually as  it only appears when using a ipad. Ive tried tricking the site using differnet browser agents but i think its looking at 8 different variables.

Any help much appreciated

Ian

Answer (score 0):

If the user is using a webclip (i.e. the web page saved to the home screen, `window.navigator.standalone` will be true.

You can hence use:

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {
    // from webclip
} else {
    // normal
}
```

This info is from the Safari Reference here: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html